# On select disable text fields

Tags: php

I have a form as shown below if I select `company` from dropdown disable `collegename`, `course` and `year`. If I select `college` disable `company name` and `date of join`. Please help regarding this. I need some help on how to disable text fields when we select value from drop down

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="" onSubmit="submit;">
<center><table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="width:650px">

<tr>
<td><b>Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Father Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname"></td></tr>


<tr><td><b>Gender</td>
<td><select name="gender">
<option value="na">Select</option>
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Email</td>
<td><input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>

 <tr>
<td><b>Date Of Birth</td>
<td><input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" required></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Mobile Number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mn"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Parent Number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="pn"></td></tr>

<tr> 
<td><b>Address</td> <td><textarea name="address" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Coll/Comp ID Num</td>
<td><input type="text" name="idnum"></td></tr>

<tr><td><b>Company/College</td>
<td><select name="ccname">
<option value="na">Select</option>
<option value="company">Company</option>
<option value="college">College</option>
</td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>College Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="colname"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Course</td>
<td><input type="text" name="course"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Year</td>
<td><input type="text" name="year"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Company Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="comname"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Date Of Join</td>
<td><input type="text" name="doj" id="datepicker" required></td></tr>


<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/></td>
</tr></center>
</table>
  </form>
```

Comment: can be easily done with jquery... there are tons and tons of reference and tutorials for this...

Comment: You need to use javascript for this.

Comment: can u provide me sample code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Use some thing like this if you have problem tell me


 <script> 
      function getccname(val)
{
     if(val == 'company')
     {
     document.getElementById("colname").disabled = true;
     document.getElementById("course").disabled = true;
         document.getElementById("year").disabled = true;
     } 
     else if(val == 'college')
     {
        document.getElementById("comname").disabled = true;
                 document.getElementsByName("doj")[0].disabled  = true;
        document.getElementById("colname").disabled = false;
               document.getElementById("course").disabled = false;
         document.getElementById("year").disabled = false;

     }
     else 
     {
        document.getElementById("comname").disabled = false;
                  document.getElementsByName("doj")[0].disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("colname").disabled = false;
               document.getElementById("course").disabled = false;
         document.getElementById("year").disabled = false;

     }

}

</script>
<form name="form" method="post" action="" onSubmit="submit;">
<center><table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="width:650px">

<tr>
<td><b>Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Father Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname"></td></tr>


<tr><td><b>Gender</td>
<td><select name="gender">
<option value="na">Select</option>
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Email</td>
<td><input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>

 <tr>
<td><b>Date Of Birth</td>
<td><input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" required></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Mobile Number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mn"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Parent Number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="pn"></td></tr>

<tr> 
<td><b>Address</td> <td><textarea name="address" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Coll/Comp ID Num</td>
<td><input type="text" name="idnum"></td></tr>

<tr><td><b>Company/College</td>
<td><select name="ccname" onchange="getccname(this.value);">
<option value="na">Select</option>
<option value="company">Company</option>
<option value="college">College</option>
</td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>College Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="colname" id="colname"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Course</td>
<td><input type="text" name="course" id="course"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Year</td>
<td><input type="text" name="year" id="year"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Company Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="comname" id="comname"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Date Of Join</td>
<td><input type="text" name="doj" id="datepicker"></td></tr>


<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/></td>
</tr></center>
</table>
  </form>
```

Comment: if i select company disable collegename course and year

if i select college disable company name and date of join

Comment: stackoverflow is not a script writing service.. @vish has provided you the code atleast try to make make few edits to it..

Answer (score 0):

Call a javascript function with your drop down list, use anything like that `onclick="sample1();"` , then disable your text field using

```
function sample1(){
    document.getElementById("textfield").disabled=true;
}
```

Comment: change <select name="gender"> to <select name="gender" onclick="sample1();"> and then change <input type="text" name="comname"> to <input type="text" name="comname" id="textfield"> & lastly add my provided js function.